# Backtesting an algorithm from universe of stocks

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

I am using python to develop a algorithm that identifies certain patterns in time series from 500 stocks between 2010-01-01 and 2020-12-31. When I have identified a patterns a want to long(speculate that the stock will go up) or short(speculate that the stock will go down) that stock depending on what signal is generated. I also use a predefined numbers of days I want to hold the position of the stock. So what I have managed to do is the return the date I should enter a position and the date I should exit a position but I don't know how to backtest the strategy. What I want to do is to set an initial capital of a certain size, buy or sell a stock with a certain portion of the initial capital and see how the initial capital develops over time. I also want to make sure that my capital never is less than 0 so if a signal to enter a position is generated but you have to little capital to enter that position you just ignore the signal and won't make the trade. I know how to backtest this strategy when you only use one asset and not several of them and when the signals don't overlap each other.

Excuse me if the explanation is unclear.

Does anyone have a good solution how I could backtest this strategy?

[Picture of the signals when to enter and exit a position of a certain stock when signals have been generated for two assets, but I generate signals from 500 assets so this dataframe will be much bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xFPw.png)

Thank you!

Comment: You will essentially be writing a time-based simulator.  You'll have a date, a starting cash account, and a list of events.  For every loop, bump the date by one, see if you have anything to do on that date (buy, sell), record the transaction in a log, and move on. It would be fun to do.

Comment: You will want to convert your list to a different format: (date, action [buy/sell],  stock).  Then you can sort by date, and it's easy to do things in order.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I might understand the idea. So the date column can obtain the the same date as the previous row but with another stock? And I guess you could set values like 1 to buy and -1 to sell in the [buy/sell] column?

Comment: Right.  Each date step might have several actions to take.  And you could use 1 or -1, or the strings "buy" and "sell", whatever makes sense to you.  Performance won't be an issue.